# Android Studio WebView file Upload From gallery working but not from Taking photo

Tags: android, file-upload, webview, android-webview, android-camera

How to convert

```
file:/data/user/0/com...../cache/JPEG_980041_6389888734396042298.jpg
```

to this

```
[content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A16781]
```

I followed many tutorials on how to take photo and upload inside a webview using the camera AND photo gallery.

This work from gallery the log says `[content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A16781]` and the file get passed to the html `<input type="file"` but when I hit "ok" after taking a photo in the camera Log says `file:/data/user/0/com...../cache/JPEG_980041_6389888734396042298.jpg` and the file DON'T get passed to the file input :(

is there a way to modify the code to "convert" from `file:/data/....` to `[content://....`

Here AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.apptheway.wexview">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA2" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIDEO_CAPTURE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUDIO_CAPTURE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"  />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.low_latency" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.pro" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <!-- [START fcm_disable_auto_init] -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <!-- [END fcm_disable_auto_init] -->
       <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:name=".GenericFileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*,video/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

</manifest>
```

Here xml/file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="extfiles" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="external" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="my_videos" path="." />
    <external-media-path name="external_files" path="." />
    <external-media-path name="extfiles" path="." />
    <external-media-path name="my_images" path="." />
    <external-media-path name="my_videos" path="." />
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <external-path name="extfiles" path="."/>
    <external-path name="external" path="."/>
    <external-path name="my_images" path="."/>
    <external-path name="my_videos" path="."/>
    <files-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <files-path name="extfiles" path="."/>
    <files-path name="external" path="."/>
    <files-path name="my_images" path="."/>
    <files-path name="my_videos" path="."/>
    <files-path name="files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Here the code in MainActivity.java

```
@SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;
    private String mCameravideoPath;
    private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    // FILE IMAGE
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

        int timeStamp = (new Random().nextInt((1000000 - 1) + 1) + 1);
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getCacheDir();
        return File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

    }

    // FILE VIDEO
    private File createVideoFile() throws IOException {

        int timeStamp = (new Random().nextInt((1000000 - 1) + 1) + 1);
        String videoFileName = "VID_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getCacheDir();
        return File.createTempFile(
                videoFileName,
                ".mp4",
                storageDir
        );

    }

    // FOR FILE UPLOAD
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

        Uri[] results = null;

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if (data == null || data.getDataString() == null) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    Log.e("imgFileU","88 "+mCameraPhotoPath);
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    Log.e("imgFileU","94 "+Arrays.toString(results));
                }
            }

        }
        else {
            if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                File file = new File(Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath).toString());
                results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(file.getPath())};
            }
            Log.e("imgFileU","104 result "+ Arrays.toString(results));
        }

        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        String[] permissions = {
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        };

        requestPermissions(permissions, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        String appNAME = getString(R.string.app_name);
        String stubdomain = getString(R.string.stubdomain);
        AtomicReference<String> fireToken = new AtomicReference<>("");
        int randy = (new Random().nextInt((10000000 - 1) + 1) + 1);

        mWebView = new WebView(this);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        webSettings.setUserAgentString("stubfeedandroid "+appNAME+" "+stubdomain+" "+webSettings.getUserAgentString());

        // FOR FILE UPLOAD
        mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

        // LINKS HANDLING
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

                String url = request.getUrl().toString();

                int opensInWexView = 1;

                // IF FILE
                if (    url.contains(".pdf") || url.contains(".mov") || url.contains(".mp") ||
                        url.contains(".hv") || url.contains(".aif") || url.contains(".wav") ||
                        url.contains(".xls") || url.contains(".doc") || url.contains(".txt")
                ) {
                    opensInWexView = 0;
                }

                // URL SCHEME
                if (    url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:") ||
                        url.startsWith("mms:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") ||
                        url.startsWith("fax:") || url.startsWith("fb:")
                ) {
                    opensInWexView = 0;
                }

                // STUBSHARE
                if ( url.startsWith("stubshare:") ) { opensInWexView = 3; }

                switch (opensInWexView) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        String urlinhttp = url.replace("stubshare://","https://www.");
                        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, urlinhttp);
                        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share"));
                        break;
                }

                return true;

            }
        });

        // WEBCHROME
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
                if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mFilePathCallback = filePath;

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        Log.e("imgFileU", "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                    }
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the video should go
                    File videoFile = null;
                    try {
                        videoFile = createVideoFile();
                        takeVideoIntent.putExtra("VideoPath", mCameravideoPath);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        Log.e("vfile", "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                    }
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (videoFile != null) {
                        mCameravideoPath = "file:" + videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(videoFile));
                    } else {
                        takeVideoIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*, video/*");
                contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[]{"image/*", "video/*"});
                contentSelectionIntent.setDataAndType(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "image/* video/*");

                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null && takeVideoIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent, takeVideoIntent};
                } else if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else if (takeVideoIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takeVideoIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Upload");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
                return true;
            }

        });

        this.setContentView(mWebView);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater myMenuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        myMenuInflater.inflate(R.menu.super_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemId == R.id.myMenuOne) {
            onBackPressed();
        } else if (itemId == R.id.myMenuTwo) {
            GoForward();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void GoForward() {
        if (mWebView.canGoForward()) {
            mWebView.goForward();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't go further!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should use FileProvidet class to serve your file and get a content scheme uri for your file path.

Comment: @blackapps That is a problem, because every time I try to follow tutorials, they point androidManifest.xml and add `<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" `... but android is harrasing me when I do that I get TONS of deprecation ALERTS.... plus "The Android Support Library has reached the end of its life. 28.0 was the last release of the Android Support namespace and the namespace is no longer maintained" ... is there a newer way to do it ?

Comment: If you use FileProvider in the java file of your Activity Android Studio will suggest an import if there is no import yet. If there is then remove it and choose the right import. Use the same in manifest.

Comment: @Jintor, why do you use old support `FileProvider`? See https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider.

Comment: @CoolMind I've search all over the places, many many many answers, and it all ends up with file:/data.... insteand of [content://com.a...... I'm unable to know why and unable to fix it, can you elaborate an answer on this ? I'm really stuck. tried "androidx.core.content.FileProvider" without success... I also tried `Uri.parse(new File(mCameraPhotoPath).toString())` same, always, returns `file:/...`