# Android Camera Intent Image is not Uploaded in Webview

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-11

I got an takePictureIntent which is not null but it won't send it to the webview. Does anybody have an idea? It does work in older version 9 and under, it doesn't work in android version 10 & 11.

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go

            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                Log.d("test", "Test1");

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "\"Unable to create Image File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            } else {
                takePictureIntent = null;
            }
        }
```

I get my Log so I know it's not null and it should have created the photoFile:

```
D/test: Test1
```

The app works if I select images:

```
            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

        Intent[] intentArray;
        if (takePictureIntent != null) {
            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
        } else {
            intentArray = new Intent[0];
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

        return true;
```

**Edit 1:**

I tried to log the absoluet path if there is even an image and hat works as well. Why doesn't it put the image into the webview?

```
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            //if (photoFile != null)
            //try{
                mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));

            Log.d("test", photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
           // } catch (Exception e) {
                //takePictureIntent = null;
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "\"Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           // }

D/test: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20210407140742_2243265910829120097.jpg
```

**Edit 2**

Now I also tried it with the following:

```
package ch.actum.DCD;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public WebView webView;
ImageView iv;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
private String mCameraPhotoPath;
private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
Timer t = new Timer();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainview);
    CheckInternetState();
    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            switchView();
        }
    };
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 1, 1000);
}

public void switchView() {
    Intent obj = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, noconnectionActivity.class);
    if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
        t.cancel();
        startActivity(obj);
        webView = null;
    }
}

public void CheckInternetState() {
    if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_no_connection);
    } else {
        //        Show Spinner when app is loading
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();

//             Start WebView
        StartWebView();
    }
}

public void StartWebView() {
    //        WebView to View DCD Website
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.doccardiacdevice.com/scan_Mobile"); // website on app launch
    webView.setWebViewClient(new xWebViewClient()); //we would be overriding WebViewClient() with custom methods
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new chromeView()); //we would be overriding WebChromeClient() with custom methods.
}

class xWebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressDialog.show(); //showing the progress bar once the page has started loading
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressDialog.dismiss(); // hide the progress bar once the page has loaded
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        webView.loadData("", "text/html", "utf-8"); // replace the default error page with plan content
        progressDialog.dismiss(); // hide the progress bar on error in loading
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet issue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_no_connection);
    }
}



public class chromeView extends WebChromeClient {
    // For Android 5.0+
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
        // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
        if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mFilePathCallback = filePath;


        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go

            File photoFile = null;
         //   try {
                //photoFile = createImageFile();
                File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                path.mkdirs();
                photoFile = new File(path, "TEMP.jpg");
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
             //   Log.d("test", "Test1");

           /* } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "\"Unable to create Image File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }*/

            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            } else {
                takePictureIntent = null;
            }
        }

        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

        Intent[] intentArray;
        if (takePictureIntent != null) {
            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
        } else {
            intentArray = new Intent[0];
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

        return true;

    }

    // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
        Log.d("test", "Test2");

        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

        try {
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            File imageStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    , "AndroidExampleFolder");

            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }

            // Create camera captured image file path and name
            File file = new File(
                    imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                            +     String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            + ".jpg");

            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

            // Camera capture image intent
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");

            // Create file chooser intent
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

            // Set camera intent to file chooser
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                    , new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});

            // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("test", e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
    }

    //openFileChooser for other Android versions
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                String acceptType,
                                String capture) {

        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
    }

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

        Uri[] results = null;

        // Check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null || data.getDataString() == null) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    Log.d("T1", mCameraPhotoPath);
                    Log.d("T3", results.toString());
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    Log.d("T2", results.toString());
                }
            }
        }

        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        //mFilePathCallback = null;

    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;

            }

            Uri result = null;

            try {
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                    result = null;

                } else {

                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;

        }
    }

    return;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    try {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        return imageFile;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("test", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

public static class DetectConnection {
    public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager con_manager = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        return (con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected());
    }
}
```

}

**Edit 3**

Or is there an alternative way to upload images to a webview?

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same type of issue.... still unfixed... look my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66533875/android-studio-webview-file-upload-from-gallery-working-but-not-from-taking-phot

Comment: I'm thinking I could explore webRTC instead... .getUserMedia -> take photo -> upload the blob from canvas to php... https://html5.tutorials24x7.com/blog/how-to-capture-image-from-camera

Comment: Maybe you should use `FileProvider`.

Comment: Hi Felix, I explored WEBTRC and getUserMedia->stream-to-video->snapshot-to-a-canvas->canvasBLOB-to-ajax and it's working VERY well : see a starting point here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67205632/webrtc-take-snapshot-from-webcam-and-save-it-to-server-in-php-with-iphone-whe