# WebRTC snapshot from webcam and save it to server in PHP : iPhone Safari crashes when resolution higher than 2096

Tags: iphone, ajax, webrtc, mobile-safari, getusermedia

I have a WORKING code to take a snapshot from the webcam and save it in PHP via ajax... but when I try with a resolution higher than 2000, safari mobile on iPhone crashes, why and how to fix this ?

here , If I do `getUserMedia({ video:{width: { ideal: 2096` => it's all ok

But if I fo `getUserMedia({ video:{width: { ideal: 3096` => it crashes :(

HTML

```
<video id="precam" playsinline="true" muted autoplay style="max-width:90%;" ></video>
<canvas id="canvax" ></canvas>
<div onclick="sendToServer('ajaxanswer');">SAVE</div>
<div onclick="webcamFRONT();">SWITCH TO FRONT CAM</div>
<div id="ajaxanswer" ></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
const videoPlayer = document.querySelector("#precam"); 
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvax");

function webcamREAR () {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video:{width: { ideal: 2096 },facingMode: "environment"}, audio:false })
        .then(stream => videoPlayer.srcObject = stream)
        .catch(error => {console.error(error);});
}

function webcamFRONT () {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video:{width: { ideal: 2096 },facingMode: "user"}, audio:false })
        .then(stream => videoPlayer.srcObject = stream)
        .catch(error => {console.error(error);});
}
        
function wcanvasim () { 
    canvas.width = videoPlayer.videoWidth; canvas.height = videoPlayer.videoHeight;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(videoPlayer, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

webcamREAR();

function sendToServer (divID) {
    var pcache = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000) + 1);
    var params = "divID="+encodeURIComponent(divID)+"&canvablob="+encodeURIComponent(canvas.toDataURL());
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhr.open("POST", "/file.php?pcache="+pcache, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) { if (xhr.readyState == 4) { $("#"+divID).html(e.currentTarget.responseText) ; } }
    xhr.send(params);
}
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$whereTOdeBlob = '/path/to/server/'.mt_rand().'.png';
$canvablob = ( $_REQUEST['canvablob'] ?? '' ) ;
$canva64 = explode('base64,',$canvablob)[1] ?? '';
file_put_contents(INCLUDE_PATH_ROOT.$whereTOdeBlob,base64_decode($canva64));

// CONVERT TO JPG
// ADD TO DATABASE
// ANY STUFF YOU WANT ;)

echo '<img src="'.$canvablob.'" />';

?>
```

******* The question is : why large resolution makes safari mobile crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [`.toDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) to encode that huge image as a [lossless .png file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics). That probably generates a multimegabyte string that you try to POST. Somewhere along the way Safari probably **runs out of contiguous RAM** and gacks, either on allocation or garbage collection. It's also likely your POST's payload size [exceeds php's maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size).

Try `.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.3)` to get a low-quality [JPEG image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Typical_usage), which will generate a much smaller string.  If that works, crank up the quality (0.3 to 0.4, 0.5, etc).

Or, better, convert your canvas [to a binary Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob), then post that. It will take less space than a data URL. Something like this.  Not, repeat not, debugged.

```js
function sendToServer (divID) {
    var pcache = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000) + 1)
    canvas.toBlob (function (blob) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
      xhr.open("POST", "/file.php?pcache="+pcache, true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) { 
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) 
           $("#"+divID).html(e.currentTarget.responseText) 
      }

      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('divID', divID)
      fd.append('canvaBlob', blob)
      xhr.send(fd)
    }, 'image/jpeg', 0.8)
}
```

Also, try constraining the height of the image as well as the width.  If your camera is in portrait mode and you ask for a 2K width you may get a 4K height if you let `.getUserMedia()` choose whatever height it wants; it obeys a default aspect ratio.

Finally, in a practical sense images at so high a resolution usually have to be downsampled before you use them. Lower-resolution JPEG images usually meet practical requirements. So simply capture lower-resolution images. (If you're a photographer making photos to print in glossy magazines, you already know about the limitations of iPhone cameras.)

Comment: Thanks :) I did `canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.9)` and ideal 3069 and it's working very well !!!!